How to diagnose WI-Fi problem (Realtek RTL8723DE adaptor)
I have an odd problem with a laptop running Ubuntu 24.04.1 (kernel 6.8.0.49-generic) with Realtek RTL8723DE wi-fi adaptor.
If it loses wi-fi connection, I lose complete internet connectivity, even after a reboot. The symbol shows a connection (and it obtains an ip address) but ping google.com gives at most 5 return pings before connection dies.
Restarting the connection, either by rebooting the router or toggling the setting gives 5 more successful pings before things start timing out again.
The only way to restore connection is to connect via LAN, let the connection 'settle down', and then remove the network cable - the laptop stays Wi-Fi connected and gets internet.
How would I diagnose what the issue with the connection is? The drivers are the correct ones (lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 gives:)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8723de

and this driver has been working successfully since I upgraded to 24.04.1 and kernel versions starting 6.8.xxx in summer.
The only change in networking since the upgrade has been a change of router, which is tri-band (2.4GHz/5GHz/6GHz) and provides IPv4/IPv6 DNS and connectivity. The laptop only ever connects on the 2.4GHz band - other devices on the same network do not have this failing connection issue.
EDIT (more laptop specs): HP 15-db0598sa 15.6" Laptop, AMD A6-9225 processor, 8GB memory, AMD Radeon R4 Graphics and Realtek RTL8723DE wi-fi adaptor.
